# Random.Choice from List That Never Compares Two List Elements Twice (Python)

Tags: python, random

I am currently trying to create a program that randomly chooses two items at a time from a list for the user to compare, WITHOUT **comparing two items twice** OR the **same item to itself**.

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

In `list1`, i would like to use a random.choice:

```
item_chosen = random.choice(list1)
print(item_chosen)
item_chosen2 = random.choice(list1)
print(item_chosen2)
```

The problem here is that `item_chose` may be the same as `item_chosen2`, and that if I set a loop, the same comparisons will be made more than once. Also, the program needs to realize when all list items have been compared to one another (it would take far too long to manually code a comparison between all of multiple items in every combination possible).

Answer (score 5):

Use `random.sample`:

```
item1, item2 = random.sample(list1, 2)
```

This gets two unique elements from `list1` (i.e. `item1` and `item2` are guaranteed to be different).

Comment: Thank you very much nneonneo, I will use random.sample instead of random.choice

Comment: `random.sample` doesn't remove items from the list.  Subsequent calls can select items that have already been selected, so it's possible to select two items twice.

Comment: you can use random.sample and remove the items from the main list.But you will get same numbers if your original list contains duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle the list (using [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle)) and take the items two at a time in order from the shuffled list.

Comment: I have received a solution for my random.choice troubles. The solution is obviously to use random.sample or random.shuffle, instead. I appreciate the feedback!

Now I just face the second problem of allowing the program to realize when all items have been compared so that it can terminate. Does anybody know if random.shuffle has the ability to do this (before I recode my entire program). ;)

Thank you all,

Joseph

Comment: Thanks Bill! I will try implementing this this random.shuffle.

Comment: @Joseph No problem.  To compare all items, after you shuffle the list, just loop through it and pop two items from it each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using `random.shuffle()` instead of `random.choice()`:

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']

random.shuffle(list1)
item_chosen = list1.pop()
print(item_chosen)
item_chosen2 = list1.pop()
print(item_chosen2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, Zero! I think it covers everything I need implement random.shuffle in my program.